# タグ [shellscript] と [shell] のマージを提案します

Tags: 討議, 完了, タグ, タグの別名の提案

シェルスクリプトに関するタグ、[shellscript](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shellscript) と [shell](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell) のマージを提案します。

これらの使い分けとして、[shellscript](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shellscript) は言語を指し、[shell](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell) はその実装、あるいは対話的機能面を指すとも考えられます。過去の質問においては、一部そういった区別が行なわれている雰囲気は感じられます。しかし、一貫していません。これらの区別は難しすぎると思います。

英語版では、[`shellscript` は `shell` の別名となっています](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/shell/synonyms)。

Comment: 自分は使い分けてきた側です。質問一覧を見てみると [shell] の質問の殆どは [shellscript] タグや [bash] 等のタグに書き換えても問題なさそうだったのでマージまでいかなくとも [shell] タグを burniate できないか考えたのですが、2 つ 3 つの質問で [shell] タグ以外にマッチしそうなタグを思いつかなくて悩んでいます（[例1](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/69025/19110)、[2](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/24309/19110)）。別名にするのが運用上は良いのかなあ……。質問を検索するときは別名になっていても困らない気はしています。

Comment: @nekketsuuu `shellscript` の方が意味としては狭いと思うので、これに当て嵌らない質問は今後も有りそうですね。英語版に倣って、別名というのが丸いと思います。マージは簡単に戻せないようなので、懸念が有るならば直ぐにはやらない方が良いのかも知れませんが。

Comment: 別名にいたしましょうか。念のため確認なのですが、別名にするとして、どちらをどちらに map したいですか？　[shellscript] タグが [shell] タグに変わる方向（[shell] だけが残っていく方向）で認識あっていますでしょうか。

Comment: @nekketsuuu そうですね。英語版と同じく [shellscript] タグが [shell] に変わる（別名になる）のが良いと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[shellscript](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shellscript) -> [shell](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell) の方向に別名を設定しました: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/shell/synonyms

タグのマージは undo が難しいので今は行わずに一旦これで運用してみて、[shellscript](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shellscript) は滅ぼしたいとなったらまたメタに投稿ください。

Answer (score 1):

単に 'shellscript' だけだとシェルの種類によって文法も違うので、シェルスクリプトに関する質問は [bash](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) や [ksh](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ksh) など具体的なタグ名が付いていれば十分な気がします。

英語版における ['shell' のタグ説明](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/shell/info) では、より具体的なシェルのタグ名を使用するよう勧めています。

> For questions about shell scripting, please use a more specific tag such as 'bash', 'powershell' or 'ksh'.

また、英語版においては ('shellscript' タグの代わり？に) 'script' タグがありますが、ちょうどいま 'script' タグは無くす方向で進めているところのようです。

[The [script] tag is being burninated - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406928/2322778)

---

参考までに、他の関連サイトでの 'shell' の説明を載せておきます。

[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tags/shell/info)

> A shell is terminology for a command-line interpreter most commonly used with Unix-like operating systems, but also used to interact with GUI-based operating systems in a more granular fashion. Not only does it allows the user to run programs from a text interface, but frequently offers basic programming features such as variables, substitution, output redirection, and wildcards.

[Super User](https://superuser.com/tags/shell/info)

> A shell is software that lets users interact with the operating system, usually by typing at a command-line.

なお、Ask Ubuntu だと ['shell' は 'command-line' の別名になっています。](https://askubuntu.com/tags/command-line/synonyms)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: シェルスクリプトは他の言語とは違う事情が多く、シェルを特定したタグのみを付けるのが良いとは言えない質問が多いと思います。
事情というのは、
〔質問者が、使用しているシェル固有の機能に限定した回答を求めているケースが少ない〕
〔シェルスクリプトは外部コマンドに依存する事が普通で、質問の内容も実際にはコマンドの使い方だったりする〕
〔時には、ターゲットとする環境が特定のシェルでは無く、かといって完全なPOSIX sh互換という訳でも無い集合であったりもする〕
といった事です。